# How to attach event listener via configuration instead of module bootstrap?

Tags: php, events, zend-framework3

In ZF3 you would normally attach your event listener for the `MvcEvent`'s in your module's Module.php like so:

```
<?php

namespace MyModule;

class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
    {
        $eventManager = $event->getApplication()->getEventManager();

        $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, function(MvcEvent $event) {
            // Do someting...
        });
    }
}
```

Now there are two typical situations where your Module.php can grow big:

1. Your module has to handle multiple (or even all) `MvcEvent`'s and maybe even treat them in different ways.
2. Your module has to perform multiple actions on a single `MvcEvent`.

What I'd like to be able to do is to specify a class name in my module.config.php along with one or multiple `MvcEvent` names to keep my Module.php nice and clean.

Is there a way to do this in Zend Framework 3?

Comment: To my knowledge there is not any built in functionality for that. You will have to build it. I would make the config, create a plugin manager, give it a method that will register all of the configured items with the shared event manager, and probably make the items be listener aggregates. That's the 10,000 foot version at least.

Comment: Also you can read that config on one of your modules' bootstrap method and attach events. But i think this's not a scalable method. In some situations you'd want to de-attach event.

Comment: @MehmetSÖĞÜNMEZ Good point, but since the attachment will be done at the onBootstrap event you could probably set a priority and in turn detach the event at a later time (with lower priority).

Answer (score 3):

@Nukeface has a great example but it does not directly answer my specific question.

## To answer my own question:

This is possible with the use of listeners. A listener can be configured in the configuration files but it cannot be mapped to an event directly from the configuration alone.

It is possible to check for a specific setting in the configuration and determine what classes to map to what events. Even `MvcEvent`s can be mapped this way.

Here's how to set it up:

#### 1. The listener

We want to listen to multiple `MvcEvent`s with one simple class. Note the class it extends.

```
namespace Demo\Listener;

class MyListener extends EventClassMapListener
{
    public function handleEvent(MvcEvent $event)
    {
        // Do something
        \Zend\Debug\Debug::dump($event->getName());
    }
}
```

#### 2. The abstract listener class

The above class needs a bit more body but that can be provided by the abstract listener class:

```
namespace Demo\Listener;

abstract class EventClassMapListener implements ListenerAggregateInterface
{
    private $configuration;

    public function __construct(array $configuration)
    {
        $this->configuration = $configuration;
    }

    public function attach(EventManagerInterface $events, $priority = 1)
    {
        $sharedManager = $events->getSharedManager();
        foreach ($this->configuration as $identifier => $settings) {
            foreach ($settings as $event => $configPriority) {
                $sharedManager->attach($identifier, $event, [$this, 'handleEvent'], $configPriority ?: $priority);
            }
        }
    }

    public function detach(EventManagerInterface $events)
    {
        // Do the opposite of attach
    }

    abstract public function handleEvent(MvcEvent $event);
}
```

#### 3. The factory

Now we need a factory that we can reuse for all our classes that need to listen to multiple events:

```
namespace Demo\Factory\Listener;

class EventClassmapListenerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $globalConfiguration = $container->get('config');
        $configuration       = [];

        if (array_key_exists('event_classmap', $globalConfiguration)
            && array_key_exists($requestedName, $globalConfiguration['event_classmap'])
        ) {
            $configuration = $globalConfiguration['event_classmap'][$requestedName];
        }

        return new $requestedName($configuration);
    }
}
```

#### 4. Configuration

In your module.config.php:

```
'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        Listener\MyListener::class => Factory\Listener\EventClassmapListenerFactory::class,
    ],
],

'listeners' => [
    Listener\MyListener::class,
],

'event_classmap' => [
    // Name of the class that needs to listen to events
    Listener\MyListener::class => [
        // Identifier
        \Zend\Mvc\Application::class => [
            // List of event names and priorities
            MvcEvent::EVENT_BOOTSTRAP => 1,
        ],
        // Another identifier
        MyEventEmitterClass::class => [
            MyEventEmitterClass::EVENT_ONE,
            MyEventEmitterClass::EVENT_TWO,
            MyEventEmitterClass::EVENT_THREE,
        ],
    ],
],
```

## Conclusion:

Although it might not really refined, I really like this idea. It is now fairly easy to add another listener and make it listen to a list of events from one or more emitters.

#### My opinion after some research

A listener itself should state what it wants to listen to, to keep things strict. Putting that information in a configuration file might result in a more complicated situation when it is not needed.

Comment: Hmm, does seem like a better approach than my answer. However, thinking about it I would add 2 things. 

1) Make the `//Another identifier` param consist of key/value pairings, where the value is the function name of the event identifiers' handling function. 
2) Find a way to pass on subsequent events. Maybe in a class' `__destruct()` function it uses class properties, defined in the abstract class, to trigger the/a next event. (Yes, there must be another(/better) way than `__destruct`, but atm cannot think of a "later" one in execution order :) )

Comment: Great input, thanks. I'm thinking of throwing together a github project just to find out how helpful this implementation will be...

Comment: Let me know if/when you chuck it online, I'd be keen to have a look! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need a few things for Listener classes:

1. Events
2. Listeners
3. Handlers
4. Factories
5. Config

Now, 2 & 3 are usually in the same class as you would usually have a Listener class for a specific purpose. Such as "Listen for Rocket launch and steer Rocket to Mars".

As such, you would need to "create" these "events" to listen for somewhere. Such as a `DemoEvents` class!

```
namespace Demo\Event;

use Zend\EventManager\Event;

class DemoEvent extends Event
{
    const THE_STRING_TO_LISTEN_FOR = 'rocket.ready.for.launch';
    const ANOTHER_STRING_TO_LISTEN_FOR = 'rocket.steer.to.mars';
}
```

Now that we have "events", we need to "listen" for them. For that we need a Listener. Because I'm limiting this to 1 example, the Handler (function(-ality) to be executed when the "event" we're "listening" for is "heard") will be in the same class.

```
namespace Demo\Listener;

use Demo\Event\DemoEvent;
use Zend\EventManager\Event;
use Zend\EventManager\EventManagerInterface;
use Zend\EventManager\ListenerAggregateInterface;

class DemoListener implements ListenerAggregateInterface
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listeners = [];

    /**
     * @param EventManagerInterface $events
     */
    public function detach(EventManagerInterface $events)
    {
        foreach ($this->listeners as $index => $listener) {
            if ($events->detach($listener)) {
                unset($this->listeners[$index]);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param EventManagerInterface $events
     */
    public function attach(EventManagerInterface $events, $priority = 1)
    {
        $sharedManager = $events->getSharedManager();

        $sharedManager->attach(Demo::class, DemoEvent::THE_STRING_TO_LISTEN_FOR, [$this, 'doSomethingOnTrigger'], -10000);
    }

    /**
     * Apart from triggering specific Listener function and de-registering itself, it does nothing else. Add your own functionality
     *
     * @param Event $event
     */
    public function doSomethingOnTrigger(Event $event)
    {
       // Gets passed along parameters from the ->trigger() function elsewhere
        $params = $event->getParams(); 

        $specificClass = $params[SpecificClass::class];

        // Do something useful here
        $specificClass->launchRocketIntoOrbit();

        // Detach self to prevent running again
        $specificClass->getEventManager()->getSharedManager()->clearListeners(get_class($specificClass), $event->getName());

        // NOTE: USE THIS TRIGGER METHODOLOGY ELSEWHERE USING THE STRING FROM THE ATTACH() FUNCTION TO TRIGGER THIS FUNCTION
        // Trigger events specific for the Entity/class (this "daisy-chains" events, allowing for follow-up functionality)
        $specificClass->getEventManager()->trigger(
            DemoEvent::ANOTHER_STRING_TO_LISTEN_FOR,
            $specificClass ,
            [get_class($specificClass) => $specificClass ] // Params getting passed along
        );
    }
}
```

Excellent. We now have a events, a listener and a handler. We just need a factory to create this class when needed.

```
namespace Demo\Factory;

use Demo\Listener;
use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;

class DemoListenerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @param ContainerInterface $container
     * @param string $requestedName
     * @param array|null $options
     * @return object|DemoListener
     * @throws \Psr\Container\ContainerExceptionInterface
     * @throws \Psr\Container\NotFoundExceptionInterface
     */
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        // If you're implementation of the Listener has any requirements, load them here and add a constructor in the DemoListener class

        return new DemoListener();
    }
}
```

Lastly, we need some config. Obviously we need to register the Listener + Factory combination. Let's do that first.

```
namespace Demo;

use Demo\Listener\DemoListener;
use Demo\Listener\DemoListenerFactory;

'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        DemoListener::class => DemoListenerFactory::class,
    ],
],
```

Now for a little known bit of config to make sure that the Listener gets registered as a Listener:

```
'listeners' => [
    DemoListener::class
],
```

Yep, that's it.

Make sure to add both of these bits of config at the first level of config, they're siblings.

Comment: This does not directly answer my question but did inspire me to try something out. Also, factories aren't needed in your case. Your class could just be an invokable since the factory doesn't do anything for it.

Comment: True for the Factory. And unless you mean actually configuring the whole "attach()" business via config, I think it does answer your question. Setting the config for a when to trigger a Listener/Handler in the config itself is not possible, setting a class as being a Listener is. However, if you figure out another way, please do post, it might inspire me to do something in a different way as well :)