# ZF3 Shared Eventmanager ignores priority

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-framework3

I have the following classes and configuration to listen for the creation of a profile. Everything works fine, but now I need to listen a second time for it and this should be executed after the first time. I thought I could use the priority here, but it seems that this priority has no effect.

Any ideas?

**Config**

```
return [
    'listeners' => [
        CreateListener::class
    ]
]
```

**ProfileService**

```
class ProfileService implements EventManagerAwareInterface {

    use EventManagerAwareTrait;

    public function createProfile(Profile $profile) {
        $this->getEventManager()->trigger(__FUNCTION__, $this, ['profile' => $profile]);
        $this->profileRepository->save($profile);
        $this->getEventManager()->trigger(__FUNCTION__ . '.post', $this, ['profile' => $profile]);
    }

}
```

**CreateListener**

```
class CreateListener extends AbstractListenerAggregate {

    public function attach(EventManagerInterface $eventManager, $priority = 100) {
        // Priority of 100 seems to be ignored...

        $this->listeners[] = $eventManager->getSharedManager()->attach(
            ProfileService::class, 
            'createProfile.post',
            [$this, 'onPostCreateProfile'],
            $priority
        );
    }

    public function onPostCreateProfile(EventInterface $event) {
        // Do something
    }

}
```

Comment: Created [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49230174/1155833) with a similar setup just earlier today. Have a looksy and see if it helps you. It uses the `SharedEventManager` instead of the `EventManager`, could be the solution to your issue.

Comment: Am I wrong or do I already use the shared manager in my listener  `$eventManager->getSharedManager()`?

Comment: Apologies, indeed you do. I'll write out a short answer, see if that helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49230174/1155833) I linked in the comments, could you try the following?

(Replace naming with your own and such)

```
namespace Demo\Listener;

use Demo\Event\DemoEvent;
use Zend\EventManager\Event;
use Zend\EventManager\EventManagerInterface;
use Zend\EventManager\ListenerAggregateInterface;

class DemoListener implements ListenerAggregateInterface
{
    use EventManagerAwareTrait;

    // You had "$priority = 100", this will cause an error in PHP >7.1 as it does not match interface
    public function attach(EventManagerInterface $events, $priority = 1)
    {
        $sharedManager = $events->getSharedManager();

        $sharedManager->attach(
            ProfileService::class, 
            'createProfile',               // <<-- first function to execute
            [$this, 'createProfile'], 
            100
        );

        $sharedManager->attach(
            ProfileService::class, 
            'createProfilePost',           // <<-- second function to execute via daisy-chain
            [$this, 'onPostCreateProfile'], 
            100
        );
    }

    public function createProfile(Event $event)
    {
        // Gets passed along parameters from the ->trigger() function elsewhere
        $params = $event->getParams(); 

        $specificClass = $params[SpecificClass::class]; // get your event managed object

        //
        // Do your magic
        //

        // Don't forget to detach this function (Handler) so it doesn't accidentally run again
        $event->getEventManager()->getSharedManager()->clearListeners(get_class($specificClass), $event->getName());

        // Trigger events specific for the Entity/class (this "daisy-chains" events, allowing for follow-up functionality)
        $specificClass->getEventManager()->trigger(
            'createProfile.post',
            $specificClass ,
            [get_class($specificClass) => $specificClass ] // Params getting passed along
        );
    }

    public function createProfilePost(Event $event)
    {
        // This function is daisy-chained by the above. Copy contents, do magic
    }
}
```